# Как реализовать при выборе из SELECT появление блоков

Tags: javascript, php

второй день пытаюсь сделать, чтобы если в селекте выбрано число 2, то появилось 2 блока.. если 3, то 3 блока.

Сам селектор:

```
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="chooseBD" class="form-label"><b>Периодичность исполнения</b>
                                        </label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="stage" name="stage">
                                            <?php for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>">
                                                <?php echo $i;?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                           
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
```

Вот какой блок должен появляться

```
                                        <div class="stage">
                                   
                                    <div class="mb-3" >
                                        <hr>
                                        <h4>Этап 1</h4>
                                        <label for="chooseBD" class="form-label"><b>Дата начала этапа</b>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="date" id="nameBD" class="form-control">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                       
                                        <label for="chooseBD" class="form-label"><b>Дата завершения этапа</b>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="date" id="nameBD" class="form-control">
                                    </div>

                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так можно. Только обязательно разберитесь с id у "даты начала" и "даты завершения" - сейчас они у Вас одинаковые, это грубая ошибка. И `label for=""` у Вас везде один и тот же - это странно (Вы же понимаете, я надеюсь, зачем нужен этот `for` у `label`и как именно его следует использовать?)

```js
$('#stage').change(function(){
    $('#block-wrap').empty(); //каждый раз очищаем обёртку, прежде чем добавлять туда блок(и)
    let val = $(this).val(); //получаем значение селекта
  for(let i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
  let elem = '<div class="stage"><div class="mb-3"><hr><h4>Этап '+i+'</h4><label for="chooseBD" class="form-label"><b>Дата начала этапа</b></label><input type="date" id="nameBD-1" class="form-control"></div><div class="mb-3"><label for="chooseBD" class="form-label"><b>Дата завершения этапа</b></label><input type="date" id="nameBD-2" class="form-control"></div></div>'; //создаём блок с соответствующим номером этапа
    $('#block-wrap').append(elem); //добавляем блок в обёртку
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="chooseBD" class="form-label"><b>Периодичность исполнения</b></label>
  <select class="form-control" id="stage" name="stage">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="block-wrap"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, про лэйблы знаю, просто копи пастил. Как раз сейчас буду переименовывать!